# How dock the developer tools in the Vivaldi web browser?

Tags: browser, developer-tools, web-developer-toolbar, vivaldi

When I open the developer tools I get the familiar tools, but they are in their own window.

How can I dock them to the bottom of the window?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's possible since Vivaldi snapshot 1.10:

https://vivaldi.com/blog/snapshots/docked-developer-tools-vivaldi-browser-snapshot-1-10-829-3/

---

> Docked Developer Tools
>   We have had a long standing request for the ability to dock Developer Tools. Well, wait no longer, we are introducing this handy feature in our very first 1.10 snapshot. All of you developers who desperately wanted this, can now breathe a sigh of relief. Of course, if you prefer them undocked, that still works too!

[image]

Answer (score 6):

It's still not possible however, there are two possibilities.

First, use [VivaldiHooks](https://github.com/justdanpo/VivaldiHooks) with their `devtool.js` hook ( this allows you to dock the devtools doing a right-click in the page and selecting [ DevTools at the right / DevTools at the bottom ] )

Or, running vivaldi with a set port for remote debugging such as:

```
vivaldi --remote-debugging-port=X # X being a port, e.g: 9222
```

And opening a web panel at:

```
localhost:X # X being a port, e.g: 9222
```

I prefer the latter since it's less glitchy, while the first sometimes "eats" part of the `window.innerHeight` of the window being inspected.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible at the moment.

You can read more about this issue in [Vivaldi's community forum](https://vivaldi.net/en-US/forum/vivaldi-browser/3821-developer-tools-not-dockable-to-the-bottom-of-the-page)